# Getting fatal error running node.js git hook

Tags: node.js, git

I'm running a git hook (pre-push) and getting a fatal error.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin node

var exec = require('child_process').exec

process.exit(1)
```

Nothing crazy, just testing things out.

And it's executable.

But when I run a push I get:

```
fatal: cannot exec '.git/hooks/pre-push': Permission denied
```

And the process hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node
```

Make sure the path `/usr/local/bin/node` does exist.

Alternative (which might be what you actually wanted to do):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Again, make sure `/usr/bin/env` exists, and that `/usr/bin/env node` returns the expected path.

Comment: Second one worked! Thanks : ) For anyone coming here later, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. Strange. I ran `which node` in the terminal thinking that's the one I should be referencing. And I read on S/O that /usr/bin/env node was kind of a hack, but I guess that's rubbish.